# Url amigables en peticiones get laravel

Tags: php, laravel, reescritura-url

Como puedo hacer las url que resultan de peticiones get y que reciben parametros amigables, es decir, tengo esta peticion:

```
    Route::get('buscarParticipante','CarreraController@buscarParticipante')->name('buscar.participante');
```

Y envio los parametros y salen de la siguiente manera en la uri:

```
buscarParticipante?search=1&carrera=1&participante=1
```

Lo que quisiera es hacer esta url amigable ya que necesito compartirla, pero quisiera que quedara algo asi:

```
buscarParticipante/search/1/carrera/1/participante/1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Route::get('buscarParticipante/{var1}/delete/{var2}','CarreraController@buscarParticipante')->name('buscar.participante');
```

Luego en el controlador puedes rescatarlas mediante  $request o bien definir una función que reciba la misma cantidad de parámetros definidos en la url

```
public function buscarParticipante($var1, $var2){
    dump($var1);
    dump($var2);
    dd();
}
```

el orden de parametros que reciba la función, será el mismo en el que se definieron en la ruta, por el contrario puedes obtenerlas por el Request

```
public function buscarParticipante(Request $request){
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Si buscas nombres de publicaciones o similar más amigable, te recomiendo esta librería: **eloquent-sluggable** puedes buscarla en github

Comment: Gracias amigo, como no haberlo visto antes, ahora una ultima cosa, tienes idea como hacer para enviar una variable desde un input para que lo reciba de esta manera el route? @César Alejandro M

Comment: Puedes enviarlo dentro un formulario como se haría normalmente. especificando el name="tunombredelcampo" y luego podrías acceder a el $request, seria algo así $request->tunombredelcampo y te entregaría el valor. Si eso no responde a tu pregunta hazla de otra forma

Comment: Gracias por responder, Entiendo lo que me comentas y es correcto pero recuerda que lo que quiere es que sea una ruta amigale al usuario y si la sigo enviando como un request me seguira mostrando los = ? & en la url